# How to pass a parameter to a function called from an on_exit event of an asynchronous task

Tags: neovim, functions, job-control

Imagine the following asynchronous job to convert a given file to odt :

```
let mdfile = 'testfile.md'
call jobstart (['bash', '-c', 'pandoc ' . mdfile . ' -s -f markdown -o test.odt'], {'on_exit': 'OnEvent'})
```

Is there a way to pass the `mdfile` variable to the `OnEvent` function ?

Comment: Use global or script-local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried *partials*?

```
{'on_exit': function('OnEvent', [parameters])}
```

This is what I do in lh-tags+lh-vim-lib to register things like: delete a temporary file and print a *finished* message on `close_cb` with vim -- I've never tried to use neovim.

Comment: Neovim fully supports partials.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. But with your solution, how could I *also* pass the "data" parameter of the job to check whether it has succeded or not inside of the called function ? I know I could create another function called by the `on_err` event, but is this possible to do it in the same function as the one called by `on_exit` ?

Comment: Also, I've taken a look at `:h partial`, but I haven't understood how I could use a dictionary for my use case... Any help would be grately appreciated, thanx !

Comment: I cannot help you with neovim specificities regarding jobs. With Vim, I only register `close_cb`, and I check the result of `jobinfo()`. See my [async job queue object](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/async.vim) in lh-vim-lib.

Comment: Regarding partials, in vim, the most useful help is the one from `function()`.